# Extract characters that repeats in same position in vector

Tags: r, string, intersection

How can I get the characters that repeat at the same position in a string?

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = paste0("a", LETTERS[1:5]),
                 col2 = paste0("b", letters[1:5]),
                 col3 = paste0("ccde", letters[1:5]),
                 col4 = paste0('?', letters[1:2], 1:5),
                 col5 = paste0(1:5, 'hello you', letters[1:2], 1:5),
                 col6 = paste0('hello', letters[1:2], 1:5, "you"),
                 col7 = c("hello1 you", "hello you2", "hello3 you", "hello you4", "hello5 you"))

#   col1 col2  col3 col4         col5       col6       col7
# 1   aA   ba ccdea  ?a1 1hello youa1 helloa1you hello1 you
# 2   aB   bb ccdeb  ?b2 2hello youb2 hellob2you hello you2
# 3   aC   bc ccdec  ?a3 3hello youa3 helloa3you hello3 you
# 4   aD   bd ccded  ?b4 4hello youb4 hellob4you hello you4
# 5   aE   be ccdee  ?a5 5hello youa5 helloa5you hello5 you

result <- c("a", "b", "ccde", "?", "hello you", "helloyou", "hello")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible approach.  Convert the strings to raw, test the first against the rest for equality, reduce the result, and use it to subset the first before reconverting it back to character.  You could do the same approach with `strsplit()` but I believe that would be slightly less efficient.

```
f <- function(x) {
  cv <- charToRaw(x[1])
  rawToChar(cv[Reduce(`&`, lapply(x[-1], \(y) cv == charToRaw(y)))])
}

sapply(df, f2) 
#  col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7 
#   "a"         "b"      "ccde"         "?" "hello you"  "helloyou"     "hello"
```

Comment: Very esoteric but super compact! very nice

Comment: this is really concise! +1!

Comment: I guess there might be a potential issue when dealing with columns that consist of strings with uneven length, since `==` in your `lapply` assumes that all strings are of the same length. Perhaps you could truncate the strings as a pre-processing step.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding - it's a good point and I asked OP on a (now deleted) comment if we could assume the strings would always be equal length before I posted my answer.  But yes, if it's necessary then pre-processing the strings to the minimum length would be trivial.

Comment: Good to know that! Now my concern is resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

## Update

As per your update on the expected output, it seems we can simplify `f` a little bit

```
f <- function(v) {
  l <- min(nchar(v))
  res <- vector("list", l)
  for (i in 1:l) {
    x <- substr(v, i, i)
    if (length(unique(x)) == 1) {
      res[[i]] <- x[1]
    }
  }
  paste0(unlist(res),collapse = "")
}
```

such that

```
> sapply(df, f)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6 
        "a"         "b"      "ccde"         "?" "hello you"  "helloyou"
       col7
    "hello"
```

---

## Previous Answer

Here is a base R option using a custom function `f` to iterate through columns (I guess there must be some other packages or functionalities which are more efficient than mine, but I have no idea about them)

```
f <- function(v) {
  l <- min(nchar(v))
  res <- vector("list", l)
  for (i in 1:l) {
    x <- substr(v, i, i)
    if (length(unique(x)) == 1) {
      res[[i]] <- x[1]
    }
  }
  trimws(
    paste0(
    tapply(
      res,
      cumsum(c(0, diff(lengths(res)) != 0)),
      function(x) {
        u <- unlist(x)
        ifelse(length(u), paste0(u, collapse = ""), " ")
      }
    ),
    collapse = ""
  ))
}
```

and you will see

```
> sapply(df, f)
       col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6
        "a"         "b"      "ccde"         "?" "hello you" "hello you"
       col7
    "hello"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late-minute edit! Nice solution

Comment: @Maël No worries, both expected output are fun to play with :)

Comment: Wouldn't `l <- min(nchar(v))` be enough?